# How to copy with robocopy the time attributes without re-copying the files

Tags: robocopy, copy, copying, attributes, transfer

I transferred the files to a new disk but found that files with the wrong year (1980) and these files I can't open with Photoshop.

I would like to copy the time attributes from the first drive to the second without re-copying files.

A large amount of data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just copy the timestamps of the original files to the copied files (1980) without having to re-copy the original files again, actually, I didn't see this before using robocopy, but I think you have to robocopy it again with the /DCOPY:T switch . It can also preserve ACLs. Alternatively, SyncThing and Gs Richcopy360 can be configured to preserve directory timestamps and ACLs.

And after doing a full search, I found that Gs Richcopy360 has a feature called "Folder Time Stamp", this will re-correct the date on the destination, no need to re-copy the files, I think this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use Robocopy to *not* copy, you can use Powershell to update the timestamps.

To update file or folder  modified dates, in Windows, similar to Linux/Unix *'touch'* utility, use Powershell's **set-itemproperty** cmdlet.

Your command would look something like this:

`set-itemproperty -path $Yourfile -name lastwritetime -value "2021-05-18 10:17:47"`

Use `get-childitem` cmdlet to walk the file tree (either one level or add -recurse option to descend the folder/file tree).

Your loop would look something like this:

```
$filelist = get-childitem C:\Users\You\* -recurse
foreach ($file in $filelist) {
      set-itemproperty -path $file -name lastwritetime -value "2021-05-18 10:17:47"
}
```

There are options associated with **Get-ChildItem** to grab *only files* or *only folders.*
In Powershell window type **Get-Help** *Get-ChildItem* or *Set-ItemProperty* for more options.